# BAD_REQUEST: GCP workspace creation request validation failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, databricks, gcp-databricks

I'm trying to connect my databricks to GCP and I have given following permissions on CLI: compute, container, deploymentmanager, iam using the command "gcloud services enable [servicename]"

I've attached a screenshot for the error I got

**BAD_REQUEST: GCP workspace creation request validation failed: The provided access token doesn't have the following permissions required on the project databricks-project: iam.roles.create, iam.roles.delete, iam.roles.get, iam.roles.update, resourcemanager.projects.get, iam.serviceAccounts.getIamPolicy, iam.serviceAccounts.setIamPolicy, resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy, resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy, serviceusage.services.get, serviceusage.services.list, serviceusage.services.enable**